# outputting ascii table in C++

Tags: c++, windows, char, ascii, iostream

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class Ascii_output {
public:
    void run() {
        print_ascii();
    }
private:
    void print_ascii() {
        int i, j;                                                           // i is         used to print the first element of each row
                                                                        // j is used to print subsequent columns of a given row
    char ch;                                                            // ch stores the character which is to be printed
    cout << left;

    for (i = 32; i < 64; i++) {                                         // 33 rows are printed out (64-32+1)
        ch = i;
        if (ch != '\n')                                                 // replaces any newline printouts with a blank character
            cout << setw(3) << i << " " << setw(6) << ch;
        else
            cout << setw(3) << i << " " << setw(6);

        for (j = 1; j < 7; j++) {                                       // decides the amount of columns to be printed out, "j < 7" dictates this
            ch += 32*j;                                                 // offsets the column by a multiple of 32
            if (ch != '\n')                                             // replaces any newline printouts with a blank character
                cout << setw(3) << i+(32*j) << " " << setw(6) << ch;
            else
                cout << setw(3) << i+(32*j) << " " << setw(6);
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    }
};
```

output:
[image]

Why do I not get a properly indented output and weird characters at the values 96 - 255 ?

Comment: Perhaps start by properly indenting your code.

Comment: ASCII table goes from 0 to 127.

Comment: Note that that won't print out ASCII on systems that don't use ASCII.

Comment: @jrok I want to print out the extended ASCII table aswell.
It still doesn't explain why 96-127 isn't properly outputted.

Comment: You have some other problems with your code... the character `a` is ASCII 97, not 161. I'm guessing it's the root of your problem, you print out a number but most of of the time not the correct letter for that number.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit afaik it's properly indented (this discussion is off-topic)

Comment: @chris Still doesn't explain why 96-127 isn't properly outputted.

Comment: I also recommend you use something like [`std::isprint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) to make sure the character is printable not. For example, ASCII 127 is not printable, and may cause your formatting to be wrong.

Comment: @Ryuji: It is _not_ properly indented (all but one line of a function body is not indented at all!), and this discussion is not off-topic. Formatting your questions is a requirement.

Comment: @Ryuji, It doesn't have to. It's a relevant comment that is something good to keep in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line doesn't do the right thing:

```
ch += 32*j;
```

You want to count by 32, that's either

```
ch += 32;
```

or

```
ch = i + 32*j;
```

I strongly recommend making the numeric and character values match during your output.  So change

```
cout << setw(3) << i+(32*j) << " " << setw(6) << ch;
```

to

```
cout << setw(3) << int(ch) << " " << setw(6) << ch;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, yeah it makes sense to derive the int from the char rather than using the variables i and j when matching the numeric and character values during output.

Answer (score 0):

Char above 127 are not part of standard od ASCII. The characters that appear in Windows above 127 depend on the selected typeface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z4t9ed1%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Doesn't explain why 96-127 isn't properly outputted.

Comment: @Ryuji: `'a'` is supposed to be at 97, so there's something wrong with your arithmetic somewhere. I suspect that _nothing_ above 96 is properly outputted, even the ones that look like they could be.

Comment: Yep, you're right, refer to Ben Voigts answer for the proper solution.